# android - adding button dynamically when each button width is different , automicatically flow to next row when width is full

Tags: android, button, dynamic, row

I need to create buttons dynamically to a linear layout. The width of each button will be wrap_content. Once the whole row is full, the button should be created in the next row.

I have seen other answers in stackOverflow where this is done, but in those cases the no of buttons in a row is constant. In my case it is dynamic, because the width of each button is dynamic based on text width.

It is similar to how tags are added to a question in this site.

e.g. the answers in one of questions was:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTag.setText("Button " + (j + 1 + (i * 4));
        btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
        row.addView(btnTag);
    }
    layout.addView(row);
}
```

But here the no of buttons in a row is constant. In my case , this will be different because the width of each button is different.

Comment: You need a FlowLayout: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Comment: @DerGolem flow layout is the answer. You can write that answer, I will mark it.

Comment: hey why my question has been marked -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a FlowLayout, which is an `Extended linear layout that wrap its content when there is no place in the current line`.

Check this out: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GridLayout ?

```
    linearLayoutParent = findViewById(R.id.ll_buttons_parent); // container layout or parent layout - orientation vertical
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_horizontal_layout, linearLayoutParent, false);
    LinearLayout linearLayoutButton = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_button_horizontal);
    int rows = 3;
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
        gridLayout.setColumnCount(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Button optionButton = new Button(this);
            optionButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            optionButton.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
            gridLayout.addView(optionButton); // adding buttons to grid layout
        }
        linearLayoutButton.addView(gridLayout); // adding grid layout to vertical linear layout row by row
    }
    linearLayoutParent.addView(linearLayoutButton); //adding linear layouts to container layout
```

---

Container : ll_buttons_parent

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_buttons_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

---

button_horizontal_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ll_button_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#F8CCCC"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```